# Vim running with a python interface error: can't load library libpython

Tags: vim, python

Error when `:py print 1`: Could not load library libpython2.7.a

I tried to compile vim on ubuntu 12.04 with both python2 and python3 supports. (I also compiled and installed python by myself.). I checked `:h python-dynamic` and tried to place the related python library under the environment path. But still, `:py` and `:py3` both don't work. (However there is no problem if I compile vim under the system python versions.)

Here is my configuration before make:

```
./configure --with-features=huge \
        --enable-gui=gnome2 \
        --enable-pythoninterp=yes \
        --with-python-config-dir=/home/bohr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/config \
        --enable-python3interp=yes \
        --with-python3-config-dir=/home/bohr/local/python3.3/lib/python3.3/config-3.3m \
        --prefix=/usr/local
```

Comment: Define "not work": does 3.3 work?

Comment: Updated. I used python2.7 and python3.3.

Answer (score 0):

install earlier python 2.7.4 (instead of 2.7.5) and 3.3.1 (instead of 3.3.2)
use `--enable-shared`

install the latest vim (mine is 7.3.1242) and "ta-ta!" everything works.